# saving file to IOS device using air

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I've been trying to save file from server to an ios device using urlstream but it doesn't work (it works fine on android devices . I tried using(documentsDirectory) but it doesn't work  too .I used many other methods like (file.download )  and others but none is working .  Any help please

I am using flash pro cs6 .

script sample :

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

var urlString:String = "http://example.sample.mp3"; 
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString); 
var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream(); 
var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded); 
urlStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);


urlStream.load(urlReq); 

function loaded(event:Event):void { 
    urlStream.readBytes(fileData, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable); 
    writeAirFile(); 

} 

function writeAirFile():void { 
   var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("sample.mp3"); 
   var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
   fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE); 
   fileStream.writeBytes(fileData, 0, fileData.length); 
   fileStream.close(); 


   trace("The file is written."); 
}

function progressHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace ("progressHandler: " + event);

    }
```

Comment: Try opening it async and wait for close event. Also there are some strange preventBackup properties (`var cacheDir:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("cache"); cacheDir.preventBackup = true;`), but I don't remember using such.. As long as I remember, cache dir did the magic, but must store only files that you can replicate later on (as cache is cleared from time to time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested on iOS

```
_urlString =  "http://example.sample.mp3";
_urlReq = new URLRequest(_urlString);
_urlStream = new URLStream();
_urlStream.addEventListener(flash.events.ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler, false, 0, true);
_urlStream.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, saveFileToDisc, false, 0, true);                       
_urlStream.addEventListener(flash.events.IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler, false, 0, true);
_urlStream.load(_urlReq);


private function progressHandler(evt:flash.events.ProgressEvent):void {
trace("progress: " + event.target.progress);
}

private function errorHandler(evt:flash.events.IOErrorEvent):void {
//do something
}

private function saveFileToDisc(event:flash.events.Event):void {
_fileData = new ByteArray();
_urlStream.readBytes(_fileData, 0, _urlStream.bytesAvailable);

_file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("sample.mp3");
_file.preventBackup = true;
_writeFileStream.addEventListener(flash.events.IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, filestreamErrorHandler, false, 0, true);
_writeFileStream.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.CLOSE, fileSaved, false, 0, true);             
_writeFileStream.openAsync(_file, FileMode.UPDATE);         
_writeFileStream.writeBytes(_fileData, 0, _fileData.length);            
_writeFileStream.close();
}

private function filestreamErrorHandler(evt:flash.events.IOErrorEvent):void {
//do something
}

private function fileSaved(closeEvent:flash.events.Event):void {
//trace("file saved");
_writeFileStream.removeEventListener(flash.events.IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, filestreamErrorHandler);
_writeFileStream.removeEventListener(flash.events.Event.CLOSE, fileSaved);
_urlString = null;
_urlReq = null;
_urlStream = null;
_file = null;
_fileData.length = 0;
_fileData = null;
}
```

Comment: this is not working can you send me (example.fla) file  please ?

Comment: Can you explain what results you are getting? What isn't working?

Comment: How are you looking for the saved image? i.e. trying to find it?

Comment: No permissions are asked for when saving files. Run your app and save the file in the applicationStorageDirectory. You then need to connect your device to Xcode, Window menu > Organizer. Select your device from the left hand menu then click the Applications menu option just underneath the device name. Select the app icon that you are interested in the  click the Download button at the bottom of the window. Save the file to your desktop. Then option click on that file and choose 'Show Package Contents'. You should be able to see your saved file in there.

Comment: But it will not be  usefull this way. Can't I play the downloaded file directly from my ios device as I do with the purchased music files? Is there a way?

Comment: The steps mentioned above are so you can confirm that a file is being saved to your device.

Comment: Thanks too much the problem was that the file  does exist but the Loader class can't load it. I used the stageWebView instead and it works fine Thaaaaaanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Two obvious problems:

This line:  `urlStream..addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);` has ' .. ' which is wrong.

Also you never write anything into your ByteArray.

Answer (score 0):

set the 3rd parameter to 0 to make sure to read the entire data:

```
urlStream.readBytes(fileData, 0, 0); //0 = read all
```

Besides URLStream is not meant for that type of operation (it is meant to stream the loading of binary data). I personally do this using URLLoader (loading in binary) and everything works perfectly and save copy on folder.

Comment: urlStream is reading the entire data and saving it perfectly on desktop or android it has problem only on ios